# How to reference a just created column in mysql view?

Tags: mysql, view, reference

I need to create a mysql view like this:

the second column is calculate from the first view column. How can I reference the first column name to define the second one?

```
create view v_data
as select
   ..... AS 'first_view_column',
   (here can I reference 'first_view_column' directly and how to ?)*20 AS 'second_view_column'
from tb;
```

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use (SELECT first_colum_alias)

```
SELECT ... AS first, other+(SELECT first)
FROM ...
```

Answer (score -2):

You just use regular `SELECT` syntax:

```
CREATE VIEW v_data AS
 SELECT col1, (COL1*20) AS col2
  FROM tb;
```

Comment: I try 'create view v_data
as select
   tb.data AS 'first_view_column',
   'first_view_column'*20 AS 'second_view_column'
from tb;' it tells: " invalid column 'first_view_column' "

Comment: Use `tb.data` instead of `first_view_column` when you specify the second column. e.g. `(tb.data*20) AS second_view_column`. Also, go easy on quotation marks. Single quotes treat enclosed text as a string, not column name. Use backticks if you need to escape column names. That shouldn't be necessary with the names you have.

Comment: Actually first_view_column is calculate from tb.data; while defining second_view_column, I do not want to do the calculation again. I want to reference first_view_column directly (and do calculation on it, not on tb.data)

Comment: You can't reference the column alias (e.g. `first_view_column`) when defining the second field. Therefore you need to perform the same calculation again for the second column. Alias access is only available in `GROUP BY`, `HAVING` and `ORDER BY`.